# Find total no of items as the result of ng-if?

Tags: html, angularjs

In my new project,called "Gold loan management system",I need to fetch the ornaments name from ornament table with the specified GLID.GLID is not unique,So we may have  more than one row with same GLID and ornament name.[ornament name with weight](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8alG8.png)

Now i want to calculate the number of ornaments after perform ng-if.I used  "{{ornamentdata.length}}" Which getting the totalno of ornaments in the ornament table.How can we find the total no of ornaments getting as the result of ng-if ?

**index.html**

```
   <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">     
   <tr ng-repeat="ornament in ornamentdata" ng-if="ornament.GLID == cstmrdetails.GLID">
   <td>{{$index }}</td>
   <td>{{ornament.ORNAMENT}}</td>
   <td>{{ornament.WEIGHT}}gm</td> 
   </tr>
   </table >
```

Comment: What would you be doing with this if count in your UI?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen To print the total no of items with the GLID

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use angular filter instead of ng-if **`ng-repeat`** expression allows filtered results to be assigned to a variable. This variable will be accessible from current scope so you can use it to count the number of elements in it.

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <tr ng-repeat="ornament in (filteredItems = (ornamentdata |  filter : {GLID: testid}))" >
      <td>{{$index }}</td>
      <td>{{ornament.ORNAMENT}}</td>
      <td>{{ornament.WEIGHT}}gm</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
 <p>Number of filtered items: {{filteredItems.length}}</p>

</body>
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/RAr1fziDCgVzl0otB1uS?p=preview)**

Comment: This gets my vote for avoiding creating a custom filter (as I would have done). Better to keep it simple.

Answer (score 1):

first add class to ng-repeat raw and then create another raw and call a function. from that get length of the rows

```
 <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">     
       <tr ng-repeat="ornament in ornamentdata" ng-if="ornament.GLID == cstmrdetails.GLID" class="row-count">
       <td>{{$index }}</td>
       <td>{{ornament.ORNAMENT}}</td>
       <td>{{ornament.WEIGHT}}gm</td> 
       </tr>

       <tr  ng-init="getCount()">
       <td> count{{count }}</td> 
       </tr>
   </table >


       $scope.getCount = function(){

          $timeout(function(){
             $scope.count = document.getElementsByClassName('row-count').length;
          });

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a filter called `filterWithCondition`

In Your Html

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">     
   <tr ng-repeat="ornament in filteredData = (ornamentdata | filterWithCondition:'GLID':cstmrdetails.GLID)">
      <td>{{$index }}</td>
      <td>{{ornament.ORNAMENT}}</td>
      <td>{{ornament.WEIGHT}}gm</td> 
   </tr>
   Filtered Data Count is {{filteredData.length}}
 </table >
```

The Filter is like below

```
app.filter('filterWithCondition', function() {

  return function(items, itemKey, compareWith) {

    var filtered = items.filter(function(item){
      return item.itemKey == compareWith
    })

    return filtered;

  }

});
```

plnkr demo [Filter Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/ywBKv074v4qxrvdjEJv1?p=preview)